Android.Views.InflateException when trying to migrate a SearchBar custom renderer in .net MAUI
My Exact issue and same code is already reported by someone at the below git link. The code samples are also present in the GIT reported issue.
When migrating my Xamarin app to MAUI and when using a Custom SeachBar/SearchBarRenderer the application crashes with below error.
GIT Link: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/22522
Does someone has some solution for same or has faced a similar issue and found an alternative.?
    {Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #93 in com.extendaretail.mobileaccess:layout/abc_search_view: Binary XML file line #93 in com.extendaretail.mobileaccess:layout/abc_search_view: Error inflating class <unknown>
 ---> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #93 in com.extendaretail.mobileaccess:layout/abc_search_view: Error inflating class <unknown>
 ---> Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException' was thrown.
 ---> Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0303c3 a=-1}, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x7f10021bcom.extendaretail.mobileaccess:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty], Themes=[com.extendaretail.mobileaccess:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty, forced, android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar, forced]}

  --- End of managed Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException stack trace ---
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0303c3 a=-1}, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x7f10021bcom.extendaretail.mobileaccess:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty], Themes=[com.extendaretail.mobileaccess:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty, forced, android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar, forced]}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1007)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:991)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5579)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:196)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:191)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:187)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:934)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:954)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:290)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:276)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:272)
    at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.NavigationViewFragment.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
    at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.NavigationViewFragment.onCreateView(NavigationViewFragment.java:42)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:557)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3042)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3148)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1455)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3034)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3148)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:565)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

  --- End of managed Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException stack trace ---
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0303c3 a=-1}, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x7f10021bcom.extendaretail.mobileaccess:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty], Themes=[com.extendaretail.mobileaccess:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty, forced, android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar, forced]}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1007)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:991)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5579)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:196)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:191)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:187)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:934)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:954)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:290)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:276)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:272)
    at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.NavigationViewFragment.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
    at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.NavigationViewFragment.onCreateView(NavigationViewFragment.java:42)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:557)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3042)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3148)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1455)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3034)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3148)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:565)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

  --- End of managed Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException stack trace ---
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:934)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:954)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:290)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:276)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:272)
    at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.NavigationViewFragment.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
    at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.NavigationViewFragment.onCreateView(NavigationViewFragment.java:42)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:557)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3042)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3148)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1455)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3034)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3148)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:565)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0303c3 a=-1}, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x7f10021bcom.extendaretail.mobileaccess:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty], Themes=[com.extendaretail.mobileaccess:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty, forced, android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar, forced]}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1007)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:991)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5579)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:196)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:191)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:187)
    ... 52 more

  --- End of managed Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException stack trace ---
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:934)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:954)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:290)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:276)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:272)
    at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.NavigationViewFragment.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
    at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.NavigationViewFragment.onCreateView(NavigationViewFragment.java:42)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:557)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3042)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3148)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1455)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3034)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3148)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:565)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0303c3 a=-1}, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x7f10021bcom.extendaretail.mobileaccess:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty], Themes=[com.extendaretail.mobileaccess:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty, forced, android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar, forced]}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1007)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:991)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5579)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:196)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:191)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:187)
    ... 52 more

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

  --- End of managed Android.Views.InflateException stack trace ---
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #93 in com.extendaretail.mobileaccess:layout/abc_search_view: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:934)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:954)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:290)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:276)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:272)
    at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.NavigationViewFragment.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
    at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.NavigationViewFragment.onCreateView(NavigationViewFragment.java:42)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:557)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3042)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3148)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1455)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3034)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3148)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:565)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0303c3 a=-1}, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x7f10021bcom.extendaretail.mobileaccess:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty], Themes=[com.extendaretail.mobileaccess:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty, forced, android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar, forced]}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1007)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:991)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5579)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:196)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:191)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:187)
    ... 52 more

  --- End of managed Android.Views.InflateException stack trace ---
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #93 in com.extendaretail.mobileaccess:layout/abc_search_view: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:934)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:954)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:290)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:276)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:272)
    at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.NavigationViewFragment.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
    at crc6452ffdc5b34af3a0f.NavigationViewFragment.onCreateView(NavigationViewFragment.java:42)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:557)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:27


Not sure how they are now, but at some point they did not work at all. Use Handlers or Styles.

@H.A.H.: Do you have an alternative suggestion, I cannot use the  autocomplete shell handler since my application doesn't have shell pages, it is migrated like the old way using Main Page Navigation. Also Shell Handler is always present in the navigation/toolbar, however we want to add the same at the page level by creating a reusable component that can be used on multiple pages.

Do you find it acceptable, to define reusable control using ControlTemplates and add it to the XAML of each page?


we want to add the same at the page level by creating a reusable component that can be used on multiple pages


Resources > Styles > new file: "ControlTemplates.xaml"

App.xaml > Add the file to Merged Dictionaries like that:
<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/ControlTemplates.xaml" />


In the file ControlTemplates.xaml add:
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SearchBarTemplate" >
    <Grid BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
        <Button Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>


Create new .cs file SearchBarView extending ContentView class.
 public class SearchBarView : ContentView
 {
   public static readonly BindableProperty SearchCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SearchCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(SearchBarView ));

   public ICommand SearchCommand
   {
       get => (ICommand)GetValue(SearchCommandProperty );
       set => SetValue(SearchCommandProperty , value);
   }
 }


In your ApplesPage xaml, use the control like this:
<controls:SearchBarView SearchCommand="{Binding FindApplesCommand}"
                 ControlTemplate="{StaticResource SearchBarTemplate}"



...
Where FindApples is a relay command in your view model, and "controls" is xaml namespace to where your SearchBarView class is.
I may have butchered the code, but the concept of using templates for reusable interface is more or less this.

May be I can try this and hopefully it will work the way I am expecting it to. I will try and implement the same and check if it works.

From document .NET MAUI Shell search, we could find that SearchHandler is designed to be added at the top of the page.
SearchHandler is added inside the ContentPage And if you put it in a different location, it is not displaying.
I want search handler in multiple pages but search handler unable to achieve multiple place and not able implement inside layout other than Top of the page.
